# Toggle is-visible Class to Div Next to Trigger Element (Plain JS)

Tags: javascript, html, loops, selectors-api

This is supposed to be a very simple dropdown FAQ system, I know how to do this in jQuery but I want to learn plain JS.

I just want the individual clicked triggers to toggle the is-visible class to the content divs *next* to the clicked trigger. Like $(this).next addClass — just in JS.

I've really tried to search for this issue but 90% that shows up is how to do it in jQuery :-p

https://jsfiddle.net/48ea3ruz/

```
var allTriggers = document.querySelectorAll('.faq-trigger');
 for (var i = 0; i < allTriggers.length; i++) {

 // access to individual triggers:
 var trigger = allTriggers[i];
}

var allContent = document.querySelectorAll('.faq-content');
 for (var i = 0; i < allContent.length; i++) {

// access to individual content divs:
var content = allContent[i];
}

// I don't know how to target the faq-content div next to the clicked faq-trigger
this.addEventListener('click', function() {
content.classList.toggle('is-visible');
});
```

Would really appreciate some advice! :-)

Comment: Why are you looping through collections without doing anything?

Comment: I'm sorry, I should have explained myself better. I know that I need to do something with it, I just didn't know how to apply the addEventListener after looping through the faq-trigger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [nextSibling](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nextSibling), when you are iterating `.faq-trigger`

```
var allTriggers = document.querySelectorAll('.faq-trigger');
for (var i = 0; i < allTriggers.length; i++) {
  allTriggers[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
     this.nextSibling.classList.toggle('is-visible');
  });
}
```

nextSibling will also consider text-nodes, try [nextElementSibling](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NonDocumentTypeChildNode/nextElementSibling) also

```
var allTriggers = document.querySelectorAll('.faq-trigger');
for (var i = 0; i < allTriggers.length; i++) {
  allTriggers[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
     this.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle('is-visible');
  });
}
```

Comment: nextElementSibling that's it! Thank you! I tried nextSibling, it doesn't work, but nextElementSibling does the job.  Damn, I thought I was supposed to use querySelectorAll on the faq-content divs as well...   I got some studying to do :-p